# How to xor two string in C?

Tags: c

I have 2 string value. str and str2 . i wish to xor the str and str2

My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char str[]   =  "Hello";
    char str2[]  =  "World";
    char outupt;

    output = str[] ^ str2[]; 
    printf("%s",output)   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand what does to xor two bits (or booleans) means, but what's your definition of _xoring_ strings ?

Comment: In C, a string is just an array of `char` with a NUL character at the end. `str` and `str2` are arrays of six bytes. `output` is just one byte. So it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte i need only xor output of str xor with str2

Comment: @user3386109 may be i wrong at str[] ^ str2[] . how to xor above 2 strings with loop?

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte if you ok i need to see both, but i want char by char

Answer (score 5, accepted):

character by character:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  int i;
  char str[]   =  "Hello";
  char str2[]  =  "World";
  char output[6];

  for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
  {
    char temp = str[i] ^ str2[i];
    output[i] = temp;
  }

  output[i] = '\0';
  printf("%s", output);

  return 0;
}
```

Of course you'll need to make sure `output` is large enough to hold the result (including the null terminator) and you'll need to decide what to do if `str` and `str2` aren't the same length.

Comment: thanks bro but edit printf("%s",output); and char output[6];

Comment: @MinKoKo Ahh ok, thanks.  Same for your question, I copied and pasted from there.